Sign of cross-partial derivative
Consider a function $f(x,y)$.
Let $x, y \geq 0$, and $\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}f(x,y), \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dy}f(x,y) >0 \ \forall x, y$.
I would tend to think that the cross partial derivative $\frac{\mathrm d^2}{\mathrm dx \mathrm dy} f(x,y)$ must be non-negative for all $x$ and $y$.
Could anyone find a counter-example?
I have tried many functional forms for $f(x,y)$ ,but could not find a counterexample, where both first derivatives are strictly positive, but the cross partial derivative is negative (and both x and y are strictly positive).

please use MathJax to typeset your mathematical expressions (regular LaTeX commands enclosed in dollar signs, you can right click any properly typeset math in other questions and click "show source" to get an idea), and share your own attempts, no matter how futile, at solving the problem.

@paulina sorry this was one of my first posts. I have addressed the issues you have highlighted.

$\log{(1+x+y)}$ has positive 1st order partial derivatives and negative 2nd order partial derivatives for all nonnegative $x$ and $y$.
